# Why is this POST not being sent w/ Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form that I am trying to submit with POST. When I go to catch the POST vars, nothing is being sent.

```
<?php require_once("../includes/initialize.php"); ?>
<html><head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        e.preventDefault(); // This prevents the form submission.

        $("#messageSent").show("slow");
        $this.closest('#contactForm').slideUp('slow', function () {
           $this[0].submit(); // Actual submission.
        });                
    });

    $("#contactLink").click(function(){
        if ($("#contactForm").is(":hidden")){
            $("#contactForm").slideDown("slow");
        }else{
            $("#contactForm").slideUp("slow");
        }
    });

});
</script></head><body>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['signupSubmit'])){
echo "Post is set";
echo $_POST['name'], "<br />";
echo $_POST['email'];
}else{
echo "post is not set";
}
if(isset($_POST['signupSubmit'])){
    $signup = new Signup();
    $signup->name = $_POST['name'];
    $signup->email = $_POST['email'];
    if($signup->save()) {
        $session->message("We will contact you with details.");
    } else {
        $session->message("Failed", $signup->errors);
    }
}
echo output_message($message);
?>
    <div id="contactFormContainer">
        <div id="contactLink"></div>
        <div id="contactForm">
            <form action="test2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="name">Name *</label>
                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
                <label for="email">Email address *</label>
                <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
                <input id="sendMail" type="submit" name="signupSubmit" />
                <span id="messageSent"></span>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's the name of the file whose contents you posted here?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` prevents the form submition

Comment: I think you could use the pure javascript `$this[0].submit;` instead of using `$this[0].submit();`, which would bypass your jQuery event handler, stopping it from blocking the submission, and actually submit the form using javascript. Although jQuery might catch that anyway, so don't quote me on it :)

Comment: RJ: It outputs an empty array

Comment: jammy: I just tried that, no luck =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when you submit the form with `$this[0].submit();` it still runs the submit handler which unconditionally prevents the form from submitting. Set some flag so the form will submit after the animation.

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.data('afteranimation')){
        $("#messageSent").show("slow");
        $this.closest('#contactForm').slideUp('slow', function () {
            $this.data('afteranimation', true);
            $this.submit(); // Actual submission.
        });                
        e.preventDefault(); // This prevents the form submission.
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you please share the flag which you think I should use? Sorry but I'm a complete noob with JS

Comment: I did that: http://jsfiddle.net/d9AfJ/8/ but it still is not posting unfortunately. =(

Comment: even though it works in fiddle - when I try to capture the post with PHP; POST is not set